# Wordpress: Error establishing a database connection. Yeah, I've tried that. And that

Tags: php, mysql, macos, wordpress, osx-snow-leopard

This is driving me nuts! I have a test instance of Wordpress installed on my MacBook Pro, which has suddenly stopped working. If I head for http://localhost:9003/wp-admin/ I get:

> **Error establishing a database connection**
>
> This either means that the
>   username and password information in
>   your wp-config.php file is incorrect
>   or we can't contact the database
>   server at localhost. This could mean
>   your host's database server is down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct
>   username and password?
>
> Are you sure
>   that you have typed the correct
>   hostname?
>
> Are you sure that the
>   database server is running?
>
> If you're
>   unsure what these terms mean you
>   should probably contact your host. If
>   you still need help you can always
>   visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Hmmph! I haven't touched the config for ages. Here's how the relevant lines look right now:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

The values are all good:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u wordpress --password=wordpress \
> wordpress -e 'select user_login from wp_users'
+------------+
| user_login |
+------------+
| simon      |
+------------+
```

There's nothing in the MySQL error log, nor in Apache's error log. I've tried using a different MySQL user and a different database, but I get the same error. I'm scuppered - any WordPress gurus out there know what I'm missing?

---

Output of php --ri mysql:

```
$ php --ri mysql

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 294543 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the problem, and the solution.

http://appletoolbox.com/2010/08/phpmysql-broken-after-security-update-2010-05-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Sure web sharing is turned on?

And MySQL is running via the Preferance Pane:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-macosx-prefpane.html

Might try phpmyadmin to check the database: http://www.phpmyadmin.net

Comment: Yes to apache and mysql running. (Web sharing is clearly turned on, or I wouldn't get the Wordpress error page. Ditto mysql or I wouldn't get the command-line client output.)

Answer (score 0):

If you truly didn't change any of your configuration settings, then maybe the database connection can't be established for mundane reasons.  Perhaps a silly question, but did you try restarting your computer or at least MySQL?  Maybe MySQL is just running low on resources and cannot service your web site's request.

Comment: Good suggestion, but didn't help I'm afraid. I did restart MySQL (and eventually, out of frustration, my laptop!) but no dice. Thanks for the idea though.